# C# - Ternary Operator (?) - Struggling to Comprehend the Outcome

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

It is my understanding that the first outcome "blue", will be saved to the variable result, if the Boolean expression evaluates to true, otherwise it will store the second outcome. On this basis, why does the console print what it does, below? I'm new to programming, so please do forgive my ignorance.

```
string color = "blue";
string result = (color == "red") ? "blue" : "red";

Console.WriteLine(result); // prints red

//_____

string color = "red";
string result = (color == "red") ? "blue" : "red";

Console.WriteLine(result); // prints blue
```

edit.

Thanks all! Jay Buckman really helped me to understand this one! I think I was confusing myself by using the same phrases for both the conditionals and outcomes, therefore I've sussed it by using the following code:

```
string color = "blue";
string result = (color == "blue") ? "circle" : "square"; // variable color, is the same as the conditional, blue, therefore it results in circle (Outcome One)

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

//_____

```
string color = "blue";
string result = (color == "red") ? "circle" : "square"; // variable color, is not the same as the conditional, red, therefore it results in square (Outcome Two)

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Try and rewrite those ternary operators as standard `if` statements and see if that helps you.

Comment: It's pretty simple actually `question ? yes : no`

Comment: Your description how it works is correct and the code also behaves like your described it? So whats the problem? You seem to have understood it.

Comment: In your first example, blue does not equal red - so, the second outcome (red) is used.  You are probably confusing yourself by using blue and red for the conditional and outcomes.  Try something like `string result = (color == "red") ? "circle" : "square"`

Answer (score 2):

The first example compares the string `blue` in the variable `color` to the literal value `red`. This is **false**: they are not the same. Therefore the second option (`red`) is assigned to result.

The second example compares the string `red` in the variable `color` to the literal value `red`. This is **true**: they are the same. Therefore the first option (`blue`) is selected.

Answer (score 0):

If the expression is true, it's the left side of the colon.

blue does not equal red, therefore the first outcome will not be `"blue"`

Answer (score 0):

you should see the ternary operator as an "inline if".
Basically you have a condition, a true valueand a falsy value.

`condition ? true value : false value`

So, you have

`string color = "blue";  string result = (color == "red") ? "blue" : "red";`

which can be transalted int

`string result = ("blue" == "red") ? "blue" : "red";`

since blue isn't equal to red you are getting the false statlement which is red.